# Creating travel time isochrones using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, isochrone

I am trying to build isochrones of 5, 10, and 15 minutes walking time from service area points using ArcMAP 10.4.1. I used Digimap's Integrated Transport Network merged with Digimap's Urban Path as network source data. The first result of running the analysis, i found that some points do not seems to generate correct isochrone, or even no isochrone at all, as seen below:

[image]

I then rebuild the network and for this second time using only the Integrated Transport Network data and exclude the Urban Path, resulting:
[image]

I also have another different points dataset but when I tried network analysis to those data with the exact same first method (using ITN and Urban Path merged as network data) I did not experience any problem.

Does anyone know why and how to correct this?

Comment: "i found that some points do not seems to generate correct isochrone, or even no isochrone at all" - what happens when you make a smaller network in one of those areas?  By inspecting much smaller amounts of data more closely you may find the cause more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your time frames are to narrow, try 10, 30 and 60 minutes?

This will eliminate errors with the data if it works (and you get isochromes)